# Add element to FORTRAN pointer?

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran

I have an array `arr` in fortran going from `1 to n` where I need to test each element against the elements preceding and succeeding (i.e. `i` against `i-1` and `i+1`) - the problem being elements `1`  and `n` that have `n` or `1` as predecessor or successor, respectively (i.e. it loops).

Instead of testing the first and last elements separately, I'd rather run a loop like:

```
do i=1,n
   call testi(i-1,i,i+1)
end do
```

and define a pointer (in order to not use a dummy array and twice the memory) like

```
arrpointer(0) => arr(n)
arrpointer(1:n) => arr(1:n)
arrpointer(n+1) => arr(1)
```

to "simulate" the loop in my array. (Note that each array element is a vector - `arr(i)%vec(1:m)` )

The above does not work as each new definition of the pointer will overwrite the previous. So the question arises:

**Is there any way to actually add an element to a pointer array without deleting the previous definitions?**

PS:

As current workaround, I use an allocatable type array with the pointers:

```
type :: pointerarray
  real, pointer :: elementpointer(:)
end type pointerarray
type(pointerarray), allocatable :: arrpointer(:)

arrpointer(0)%elementpointer => arr(n)
do i=1,n
  arrpointer(i)%elementpointer => arr(i)
end do
arrpointer(n+1)%elementpointer => arr(1)
```

while replacing the loop as below does not work:

```
arrpointer(1:n)%elementpointer => arr(1:n)
```

However there might be a simpler way of which I am not aware, as type arrays for the pointers again make the code not as nicely readable.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here... But you cannot have an array of pointers without a derived type in Fortran. So your "workaround" is in fact the simplest way to realize that.

Comment: If you just want to do circular testing of an array then would you be happy with an answer that didn't involve pointers?  I feel that the background for formulating your question about pointers doesn't naturally involve pointers at all.

Comment: @alexander-vogt thank you for the input - I just believed in a more elegant solution

Comment: @francescalus I thought of inserting a dummy array - but I was worried that this would consume too much time.

Comment: @alexander-vogt btw: the original question was if there is a way to define `pointer(1:n) => arr(1:n)` and then ADD `pointer(0) => arr(n)` and `pointer(n+1) => arr(1)` without erasing the previous pointer definition and to end up with a pointer `pointer(0:n+1)`

Comment: Introducing a dummy array (to introduce halos) would be unnecessary.  I'd just be tempted to use modular arithmetic on the indices.

Comment: `dimension(:), pointer` is not an array of pointers, but a pointer to an array (as you may know).  One is quite constrained on what can be pointed at.  The easy answer, then, is "no".  If you really want to use pointers, rather than another approach, we could suggest something, but I'd say the other approaches are likely much more intuitive/simple.

Comment: @francescalus No, pointers is not a necessity - they just popped up in my mind and it would have been the first time for me to actually use them (probably inappropriately) and will take your and Alexander's "no" as the answer to my question. Thank you for the hint with using modular arithmetic - this would indeed simplify the whole expression without having to declare a pointer array. That said: any other ideas are welcome for the simple sake of learning from them.

Comment: Well in a similar situation, but I don't know if it can be useful in your case, I just defined a function giving me the next or the previous index, basically defined as  `inext = modulo(i - 1 + istep, n) + 1`, where `n` is the length of the array and `istep` is `1` or `-1` (actually it could be whatever you want).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to do this with pointers the way you envision. Instead, I recommend using an integer array dimensioned `0:N+1` that map to the desired `1:N` range. For example:

```
integer :: i(0:N+1), j 
real :: a(N) 

! -- Setup 
do j=1,N 
   i(j) = j 
enddo 
i(0) = N 
i(N+1) = 1 

! -- Then you can do: 
do j=1,N 
   ! call mysub(a(i(j-1)), a(i(j)), a(i(j+1))) 
enddo
```

Alternatively, you could use a function to define i(j).

Comment: That would be simple for sure ,however in my case the array is passed on from several previous subroutines (that also alter the array values and partially spilt arrays into two) until it comes to the necessity to do this "loop check" and will be passed further on - I'd like to avoid changing all of my previous and suceeding code (using e.g. `size` quite often). The i(j)-function however sounds like a plan but might not be simpler than the current type pointer array. I just was wondering if there was an elegant solution avoiding dummy arrays and type pointer arrays.

Comment: It's possible something will pop up with pointers; the fortran community here is very smart. I'm curious too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Fortran on this machine so haven't tested this.  It's also not entirely clear what OP's `testi` routine does.  So, this is not a complete answer, but might provide some useful (or useless) hints at a pointerless solution.

Don't forget the intrinsic function `chsift`.  One way to perform, say, a one-sided difference calculation on an array would be to write

```
arrdiff = arr - chsift(arr,1)
```

`cshift` shifts elements from one end of the array to the other unlike its cousin `eoshift` which performs an end-off shift.  Of course `chsift` is likely to require the creation of a temporary of the same size as the array (in theory it could be done without a temporary, in practice it always seems to use one) so may be unappealing on performance and memory usage grounds.